# How to use Python Selenium with Wsl2?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I've been trying to setup Selenium into my Wsl2 -environment so I could work on my scraping project. I've installed Chrome and Chromedriver but I can't seem to make chrome browser work. When I run `google-chrome` in my Wsl2 (Ubuntu 20.04.3) terminal, I get these errors:

```
[0831/073201.249844:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: No such file or directory (2)
[0831/073201.250306:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq: No such file or directory (2)
Trace/breakpoint trap.
```

Running a Selenium test-script crashes and gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                                             
File "carelink_selenium.py", line 9, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                                               
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)                                                                                                                                                                                          
File "/home/jan/.venvs/scraper/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__                                                                                                                     
RemoteWebDriver.__init__(                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
File "/home/jan/.venvs/scraper/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__                                                                                                                    
self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)                                                                                                                                                                                          
File "/home/jan/.venvs/scraper/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session                                                                                                               
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)                                                                                                                                                                                   
File "/home/jan/.venvs/scraper/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute                                                                                                                     
self.error_handler.check_response(response)                                                                                                                                                                                                
File "/home/jan/.venvs/scraper/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response                                                                                                           
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)                                                                                                                                                                                       
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: 
exited abnormally.                                                                                                                              
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)                                                                                                                                                                                       
(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so 
ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```